# Can we set a refresh rate for SignalR?

Tags: signalr

I have implemented SignalR and it is working fine. My concern is that I only want the data after minimum 5 seconds. I don't want to refresh the data if the data changes within 5 seconds of the last refresh.Is it possible?

Comment: There is no refresh rate for SignalR. You basically push data to the clients when required. Maybe you should post your code and expand on exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store the messages someplace in your app and just broadcast them whenever you choose to. Its that simple. However I question the validity of using signalr for this, there are other ways to do it that are simpler and less resource intensive.